# Hive partitions to Spark partitions

Tags: apache-spark, hive

We need to work on a big dataset with partitioned data, for efficiency reasons. Data source resides in Hive, but with a different partition criteria. In other words, we need to retrieve data from Hive to Spark, and re-partition in Spark.

But there is an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20144) in Spark that causes reordering/redistributing partitioning when data is persisted (either to parquet or ORC). Therefore, our new partitioning in Spark is lost.

As an alternative, we are considering building our new partitioning in a new Hive table. The question is: is it possible to map Spark partitions from Hive partitions (for read)?

Comment: So, did you look? I think this can help you.

Comment: I am afraid this approach is not consistent with this: _In general Hive partitions are not mapped 1:1 to Spark partitions. 1 Hive partition can be split into multiple Spark partitions, and one Spark partition can hold multiple hive-partitions._ , according to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655928/spark-behavior-on-hive-partitioned-table)

Comment: Well, maybe you should try it yourself? Did you?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery. In the next week I will re-try this in case something has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Partition Discovery --> might be what you are looking for:

*"  Passing the path/to/table to either SparkSession.read.parquet or SparkSession.read.load, Spark SQL will automatically extract the partitioning information from the paths.  "*